# NLog Archive Settings Not Correct

Tags: nlog

I have tried things suggested in accepted answers on the same topic, but have not been able to get the archiving functionality working.

These are my settings:

```
<variable name="verbose" value="${longdate} | ${level} | ${message} | ${exception:format=tostring,message,method:maxInnerExceptionLevel=5:innerFormat=shortType,message,method}"/>

<targets>
  <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File"
    fileName="${basedir}/Logs/errorlog.log"
    layout="${verbose}"
    archiveFileName="${basedir}/Logs/errorlog.#.log"
    archiveEvery="Day"
    archiveNumbering="Rolling"
    maxArchiveFiles="2"
    concurrentWrites="true"              
          />
</targets>

<rules>
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logfile"/>
</rules>
```

If anyone can identify the elusive combination of settings that I need to us, please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: Would be great if you would share the _things_ you already have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern for your archive file is not correct.
Instead of

```
archiveFileName="${basedir}/Logs/errorlog.#.log"
```

it should be

```
archiveFileName="${basedir}/Logs/errorlog.{#}.log"
```

Comment: that is it exactly. My attention to detail is terrible. Thanks for helping me out!